# Make curses output persist in console after script execution end

Tags: python, curses

After my script execution ends all of the curses output disappear, is there any way to keep the curses output in the console?

Comment: I _think_ the solution to this is to make curses use a different ... screen? Sorry, I don't remember the correct terminology here. Basically it switches to its own screen (or canvas? or drawing area?) and switches back when the program ends, but you can disable this behavior.

Comment: You could try not calling **endwin()** when your script execution ends, but your console might result a little bit messed up.

Comment: I guess [window](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/awordwindows.html) is the term I was looking for.

Comment: @guimauve I already use `curses.endwin()` at the end of the script, but it doesn't help

Comment: That's why I said **not** calling it ;)

Comment: @guimauve ah, sry. But the thing is it will screw up the terminal after the script execution so it's not a great solution :(

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446311/make-curses-program-output-persist-in-terminal-scrollback-history-after-program

Comment: @guimauve Thank you! I will try it

Answer (score 1):

curses switches to the terminal's *alternate screen* because the terminal description tells it to do that.  If you choose (or modify) a terminal description to omit that feature, on exit from curses, the terminal will show what was on the curses screen (usually shifted up by a line).

Further reading:

- [*How curses preserves screen contents?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188508/how-curses-preserves-screen-contents/39189982#39189982)
- [*How to make console output fixed in place*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39363157/how-to-make-console-output-fixed-in-place/39378789#39378789)